# C# and Linq predicate false when value is null

Tags: c#, linq, null, tryparse

I am writing a program in c# using Linq and debugging in Visual Studio.  And I am trying to test if all values in a data table can be converted to an integer.  The data table allows columns to be null (AllowDBNull=true).  I have tried using the .All method, but the predicate evaluates to false as soon as I encounter a null.  I tried adding a test for null with *or* logic and it still exits on the first null.

I wrote a little test routine.  I populate a datatable dt and then convert the types of the columns of an empty data table clone.  dt has all string types.  dtClone has types: string (correct), int (correct), decimal (correct), string (incorrect), string (incorrect) for the columns S (string), I (integer), D (decimal), NS (integer with nulls), ND (decimal with nulls).

Here is the test code:

```
    static void ALMTest()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { new DataColumn("S"), new DataColumn("I"), new DataColumn("D"), new DataColumn("NI"), new DataColumn("ND")});

        int i = 0;
        int intOut;
        decimal decimalOut;

        foreach (char c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        {
            if (i % 5 == 0)
                dt.Rows.Add(c, i, i * 3.14, null, null);
            else
                dt.Rows.Add(c, i, i * 3.14, i * 5, i * 1.75);

            i++;
        }

        DataTable dtClone= dt.Clone();

        for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {   // Does the column contain integers?
            if (dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().All(x => x[i] == null || int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(x[i]), out intOut)))
                dtClone.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(Int32);
            else
               // Does the column contain decimals?
               if (dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().All(x => x[i] == null || decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(x[i]), out decimalOut)))
                dtClone.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(Decimal);
        }
    }
```

I tried replacing

x[i] == null || int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(x[i]), out intOut))

with

int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(x[i] ?? 0), out intOut))

But the results are the same.

It is driving me insane.  The line of code stays on x[i] == null || int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(x[i]), out intOut)) for 1 test when testing S, D.  That is, it stops testing after the first failure.  It tests all 26 values in I to confirm it is an integer.  I can see intOut becoming each integer sequentially in the debugger.  It stops testing D for an integer after 3.14 fails.  And it tests 5, 10, 15 and 20 before kicking out on the first null!

Here is what the table looks like:

```
a   1   3.14    5   1.75
b   2   6.28    10  3.5
c   3   9.42    15  5.25
d   4   12.56   20  7
e   5   15.7        
f   6   18.84   30  10.5
g   7   21.98   35  12.25
h   8   25.12   40  14
i   9   28.26   45  15.75
j   10  31.4        
k   11  34.54   55  19.25
l   12  37.68   60  21
m   13  40.82   65  22.75
n   14  43.96   70  24.5
o   15  47.1        
p   16  50.24   80  28
q   17  53.38   85  29.75
r   18  56.52   90  31.5
s   19  59.66   95  33.25
t   20  62.8        
u   21  65.94   105 36.75
v   22  69.08   110 38.5
w   23  72.22   115 40.25
x   24  75.36   120 42
y   25  78.5        
z   26  81.64   130 45.5
```

The test behaves as if a null is an automatic failure, but I cannot find anywhere that behavior is described for the predicate of a Linq query.

I am new to c# and new to Linq (although not new to programming).   Does anyone know why the behavior occurs?  I might be mixing the various Linq syntaxes in a way that is not allowed. Any suggestions on a workaround that will work with All?  I would rather not have to manually iterate over each value, although I suppose I might have to.  I might be able to switch the Linq syntax to a query syntax and pull all the nulls out, but I do not know how to combine that with .All.

Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: Your welcome, Andrea. With a field value from ADO.NET, `x == null` will never be true. `(x is DBNull)` will be true when it's a null value. This is no doubt already in eleventeen different SO answers already but I am old, infirm, and addled in my wits.

Comment: If you inspect the `DataTable` you'll see those are not `null` values, but `DBNull` instances.

Comment: Thank you.  The concept of database nulls is familiar.   I would not normally use a == null syntax, but I saw it in posts.  I did not know C# has two DIFFERENT kinds of null.  I thought the IsDBNull was only a data table parameters to allow the value to be set to null.

Comment: The code functions when x==null is switched to is DBNull.  :)